# android: adding audio files to android emulator [update] permission denied

Tags: android, audio, storage

For debugging purposes, I wanted to have a couple of mp3 files located somewhere "in" my android emulator. Is there anyway to directly push files from my OS file system to the storage system of android?

If so, which directory does android keep audio files?

if not, how can I access an SD card via emulator?

[update2]: The problem in update1 solved. Should use adb push.
[update1]: I followed kgiannakakis's advice to create an sdcard for my avd. However, I got Permission denied error when I try to create new directory inside it.

```
$ cd sdcard
$ ls
LOST.DIR
$mkdir musics
mkdir failed for musics, Permission denied
$ su mkdir musics
su: uid 10016 not allowed to su
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find directions for emulating an SD card [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard).

I believe that the easiest way to copy files to the SD card is to use the [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles) utility.

See [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-sd-card-in-android-emulator-and.html) for a more advanced solution.

Comment: kgiannakakis, instead of using adb, is there a faster way of using DDMS in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding instructions at http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-sd-card-in-android-emulator-and.html on creating the 'pictures' folder, you can run the same commands from the adb shell, instead of running them from inside the emulator.

So get a command line at e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` (on 64bit windows), and run `adb shell`.
Then you can run the same commands:

```
#cd sdcard
#mkdir pictures
```

and create the directory successfully with no permission denied error.

Following same instructions, in DDMS I had to browse to `\mnt\sdcard` to find the SD card volume.

Comment: Ok. Basically the same thing was already mentioned at http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card-of.html